# what actually is buffer height property of console class

Tags: c#

Just digging through console class , can anybody tell me what is buffer height property in console class?.i tried to google but can't understand

Comment: Did you try [reading the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.bufferheight(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Read the remarks section in - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.bufferheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Remarks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Console.BufferHeight` defines the number of rows of text that can be accessed on a console window.

Not to be confused with `Console.WindowHeight` which defines the number of rows of text that *can be displayed on the console window*.

For instance, suppose you have `BufferHeight = 200` and `WindowHeight = 50`.

You would be able to write up to 200 rows of text to the console *(if you exceed this number, then the first rows of text will begin to get removed in order to create space for the new ones)*.

However, at any given moment you'd only see up to 50, because that's how much lines fit in the console window.

You'd be able to scroll down or up and display the other 150, but you'd only be able to see 50 at a time.